# mssql Npm Module returning `null` for a particular column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, npm

I am using `mssql` module from [`NPM`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to query some store procedures from MSSql Server. Everything works fine apart from one specific case. This particular piece of code returns null for `EmailText` column. I tried to execute same procedure from other places and there it returns proper value for it. I want to understand is there any limitation on the `mssql` module where in such case it returns null? Can I do something from node javascript code side to solve it?

```
sql.close()
sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(pool => {
pool.request()
  .execute('someStoredProcedure').then(result => {
    console.log(result) // Email text is null in this object as well.
    result.recordsets.forEach(record => {
      record.forEach(recordChild => {
        console.log(recordChild)
        console.log(recordChild.user_name)
        console.log(recordChild.DeviceToken)
        console.log(recordChild.EmailSubject)
        console.log(recordChild.EmailText) // returning null
        console.log(recordChild.MobileNotification)
      })
    })
  })
})
```